# Why jQuery loses 'event' (click) when some content has been loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, events, load

I am trying to load content with this next script when I select pages on the sidebar. This script works without problems:

```
if(Modernizr.history) {     
    var newHash      = "",
        $wrapperTag = $("#main-content"),
        contentTag = '#main-content-inside',
        activeClass = 'active';
    
    $("#sidebar").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        _link = $(this).attr("href");
        history.pushState(null, null, _link);

        loadContent(_link);
        return false;
    });

    function loadContent(href){
        
        $wrapperTag
                .find(contentTag)
                $wrapperTag.load(href + " "+contentTag+" ", function(response, status, xhr) {

                        $("#sidebar a").removeClass(activeClass);
                        $('#sidebar a[href$="'+href+'"]').addClass(activeClass);
                        
                        $("#menu").bind('click',function(){
                            $(this).showSidebar();
                        });

                    });
        
    }
```

This script works without probs and my HTML template looks something like this:

#### HTML Template

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul class="ul-vert">
            <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            ...
            <li><a href="pageN.html">Page N</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>

 <div id="main-content">
     <div id="main-content-inside">
         <p id="menu">Show / Hide Sidebar</p>
        <div class="text desc">(Content)</div>  
     </div>
 </div>
```

I've got a tag which is **p#menu** as an option to display or hide the sidebar. This works just **until I load any page** then I lose the **click** event.

So basically my question is:

Why jQuery losses the event after change the content?
I could solve this adding again again p#menu on **loadContent** functions, but I want to understand how jQuery works.

Thanks!

Comment: You're losing click event of `p#menu` correct? And is that why you're binding a click event after `load` has completed?

Comment: The click event exists on an element. When that element is removed/replaced, the click event will no longer exist.

Comment: Exactly. Since you replace contents of `main-content`; and `p#menu` itself is a part of it, all events on it (and any element within `main-content`) will be lost.

Comment: as I am binding p#menu again is working within the next pages. Each page has p#menu and content inside div.text.desc as a basic structure . But I think it lose the content itself!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('.fatherDiv').on('click','.childDiv', {} ,function(e){
 //insert your code here
})
```

This will bind the event handlers to the DOM selector elements not only now, but also in future (selectors added to DOM after the bindings). Now the click event fires even the specific selectors are added or replaced with new DOM elements.



Read here for further info:
http://blog.revathskumar.com/2013/10/jquery-on-avoid-losing-event-binding-for-ajaxed-contents.html