# jQuery + Selector :parent

Tags: jquery

Could you help me,

I need to do this selection but didn't work

```
$(document).on('click','input[type=radio] :parent', {} ,function(e){
      alert(">> Click img parent")
    });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v1p2c0vk/

Regards

Comment: As you see from the fiddle your html is not valid (the red color). Input does not allow any content. Also please clarify the question, what is the intended behavior you are looking for? "Didn't work" is not a good explanation...

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve so I can't help.

Comment: Also the jsfiddle is wrong. You need to add jQuery using the [JAVASCRIPT] settings and change to "IN HEAD"

Comment: apologize, what I need is to display the alert when you click on the .container, 
I modified the fiddle

Comment: Use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/v1p2c0vk/11/#&togetherjs=pHxTdcmk1a)

Comment: Do you mean this? https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/go4ypg71/

Comment: `img`?! What `img`?!

Comment: You can also so something with `if (e.target.tagName=="INPUT" || e.target.tagName=="LABEL") {
        e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: As i understand your question, you want to bind click on element which has as children radio input: https://jsfiddle.net/v1p2c0vk/12/  BUT it is really unclear what is the question here?!...

Comment: just as said A. Wolf, https://jsfiddle.net/v1p2c0vk/12/ many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent container class as a selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.container',function(e){
   alert(">> Click img parent")
  });});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this looks at the radio input's ( this could be any element ) parent and when it is clicked triggers the alert. Is this what you wanted the script to achieve?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').parent().click(function(){ 
    alert(">> Click img parent")
  })
});
```

Comment: yes but I need use other form because this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079224/why-jquery-loses-event-click-when-some-content-has-been-loaded/40912359#40912359

Comment: Have you tried this? Why do you need it in the other form?